# Find file with exact extension (and nothing following) using regex

Tags: regex, linux, find

I got a folder with about 4000 *.txt and *.txt.bak files.

I want to run linux find-command to find all *.txt files but not the *.txt.bak-files. What would be the right regex to do so?

e.g.

```
find . -regex ".*txt"
```

will find all files, including the bak files

```
find . -regex ".*txt$/"
```

will find no files at all

Comment: Are you sure about that? I just tried `find . -regex ".*txt"` and it didn't find my any `.txt.bak` files

Comment: Why use `-regex` at all? `find . -name '*.txt'` won't find `.txt.bak`, and is fully POSIX-compliant.

Comment: You are right, I was overthinking things, find . -name '*.txt' is working as intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very simple you do not need regex in find.
Simply use `find $pwd -name "*.txt"` This will automatically match your requirement.
To simplify and provide more details to extract only file name and extension you can use something like this.

```
for i in $(find $pwd -name "*.txt")
do 
  flnm=$(basename $i)
  extnm="${flnm##*.}"
  flnmnoext="${flnm%.*}"
  echo "FileName is : " $flnm " Extension is : " $extnm " File Name without extension is $flnmnoext"
done
```

This has been explained in multiple threads. Hope it helps.